# Using conditional error handling based on the current NODE_ENV but code hangs

Tags: node.js, error-handling, ejs, nodeenv

So I've made this error handler which ends a different response based on the current node environment but the code hangs in the if statement.  Printing process.env.NODE_ENV gives me a value of 'development' or 'production' based on which it is currently set to but the code doesn't seem to recognize it when entering the if statement.  If I remove the if statement the code will return the error as expected.  Thanks for your help!

```
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) => {
  // Express knows error middleware because of 4 parameters set
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500; // read status code on object
  // if not defined '500' default
  err.status = err.status || 'error';

  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV);
  currentMode = process.env.NODE_ENV;
  if (currentMode === 'development') {
    sendErrorDev(err, res);
  } else if {
    (currentMode === 'production') {
       sendErrorProd(err, res);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm setting the NODE_ENV with the following scripts


    "scripts": {
        "start-dev": "SET NODE_ENV=development&& nodemon app.js",
        "start-prod": "SET NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon app.js",
        "debug": "ndb app.js"
      },

Comment: Currently I'm patching the problem by using currentMode.includes('development') / currentMode.includes('production') because I read there are possible spaces before or after the string.  Im not sure how to confirm though.